# C++ simple code issue about cout and cin

Tags: c++, iostream

I have the following code. Everything works fine but quite different. I expect the first three `cout <<` come one after the another, so when the first message is shown in the console, the user enters the value, and then the next `cout <<` shows another message and the user enters the name of the book, and then the third `cout <<` shows the last message and the user enters the year. But it shows the first message for, I enter the value, and then it shows the next two messages together. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string AuthorName;
    string AuthorBook;
    string YearPublished;

    cout << "Please Enter the Author Name" << endl;
    cin >> AuthorName;

    cout << "Please enter the Author Book" << endl;
    cin >> AuthorBook;

    cout << "Please enter the year when the book was published" << endl;
    cin >> YearPublished;


    cout << setw(15) << "Author Name";
    cout << setw(15) << "Prominent Work";
    cout << setw(15) << "Year Published";
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << setw(15) << AuthorName;
    cout << setw(15) << AuthorBook;
    cout << setw(15) << YearPublished;

    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you enter `AuthorName`, do you have a space in between first and last name? If so, your code is reading the first name as `AuthorName`, and the last name as `AuthorBook`. C++ differentiates reading different strings based on whitespace.

Comment: can probably be solved using getline()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `getline()` since C++ stops reading your input at the first space in strings using `cin`.

Comment: would you please elaborate more?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi When you use `cin` to grab a string, `cin` will read up to the first whitespace character (space, newline, etc.) and nothing more. What you need to do is use `getline()` to read the entire line including spaces, except when it encounters a newline character (`\n`). I assume that your variable `AuthorName` has a space indicating the separation between first and last name. That is where `cin` fails and `getline()` can help you.